# Read local file line by line using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Am trying to achieve below task:

- Read file line by line
- split words in each line
- create dynamic row with each word as a column.

I tried something like below, but it's not working:

```
$.get('test.txt', function(myContentFile) {
    var lines = myContentFile.split("\r\n");
    var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");

    for(var i  in lines){
        var str = lines[i]
        var res = str.split(",");
        var row = table.insertRow(0);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML = res[0];
        cell2.innerHTML = res[1];
    }

}, 'text');
```

Comment: It is not possible to access local files from browser session. Just imagine how big security hole would it be

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923707/using-ajax-to-read-local-files

Comment: Could you describe what "it is not working" means? Do you get an error? Does your code get executed? Does it produce only half of the text? Please be specific. Have you tried to add `console.log` into your code to inspect which code is and is not executed, and the content of some variables?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have [included `jQuery` before your code executes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106864/linking-jquery-in-html), and have the `table` element with the correct `id` value in your document, something like this:

```
<table id="myTableData" border="1"><table>
```

Also make sure your text file (`text.txt`) resides in the same local folder as your `html` page.

If all these conditions are met, your code runs. Still, there are some things to tweek then. See the changes and comments I added to your code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="myTableData" border=1><table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.get('test.txt', function(myContentFile) {
        console.log(myContentFile);
        // Added: strip ending new-lines from the retrieved text:
        myContentFile = myContentFile.replace(/[\r\n]$/, '');
        // Modified: split lines also when delimited by linefeeds only:
        var lines = myContentFile.split(/\r\n|\n/);
        var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");

        for(var i  in lines){
            var str = lines[i]
            var res = str.split(",");
            // Modified: remove argument to add rows to the end of the table
            var row = table.insertRow();
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell1.innerHTML = res[0];
            // Modified: test that second element exists to prevent "undefined" output
            cell2.innerHTML = res[1] ? res[1] : '';
        }
    }, 'text');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I put the following `test.txt` file in the same folder:

```
This is a test, with something in second column
And a second line, that also has a second column
The third line just has one value
```

Then, when I open the `html` page in the browser, I get this output:

```
| This is a test                    | with something in second column |
| And a second line                 | that also has a second column   |
| The third line just has one value |                                 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put an `<input type="file" id="myfile" />` before you can manipulate your file.

And then get your file with (jquery) :

```
var myFile = $('#myfile').prop('files');
```

Otherwise you can't access it.

Comment: Thank for reply.
As an overview, i will be using it as an HTA file which will be running in local machine. Security is not a problem.
Can you please guide me where i need to mention <input type ....>

Comment: @user2529462 You can't access files by Javascript if you opened a file using `file://` protocol!

Comment: @hijarian:  Yes you can.

Comment: @trincot In the context of `$.get()` method used by the OP, you can't. File API uses completely different approach, and leads to different UI/UX, which is probably not what OP needs.

Comment: @user2529462 You can't say "security is not a problem" to web browser vendors in this case. AJAX does not work if you open a HTML document using `file://` protocol, that is, from the file manager.

Comment: @hijarian:: maybe I misunderstood what you are saying, but with $.get() it works.

Comment: @trincot Please, show the HTML + Javascript code you are using. I just have mocked up a page just to confirm this thing, *which I know already from my own past experience*, and $.get() is not firing at all from local pages.

Comment: I provided it in my own answer. It just needs a `test.txt` to reside in the same folder as the `html` file I provide the complete code of. It works for me.