# Adding placeholder attribute to input HTML

Tags: jquery, html, input, placeholder

I'm attempting to add a placeholder attribute to multiple input tags with unique classes in a form. The form is generated by a plugin so I can't add the attribute in manually. Unfortunately nothing I have tried has worked. 
Because each placeholder is different I'm address each one separately...

Here's the HTML

```
<input class="name-field" type="text" id="yourName_38_1" name="yourName" value="">
```

The jQuery I'm using

```
$(".name-field").attr("placeholder", "name");
```

When I look in the console I get the following which is referring to line the jQuery is on.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
```

My understanding of jQuery is very basic. Please help

Thank you in advance.

Dave

Comment: You haven't included jquery - have a read of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106864/linking-jquery-in-html

Comment: If you have already added jQuery then it might be getting conflict. use `$` instead of `jQuery`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load jquery plugin.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Please add this line above your `<script></script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```