# Why are images not showing on website?

Tags: html, css

Images after "my art" part are not showing. Cursor is changing when you slide under the MY ART. So images are probably there, but not showing. The problem might be in css, but i cant find it.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWKKVj

Im new in HTML, CSS and Java. I took this part from free galleries. https://codepen.io/wunnle/pen/ZLomgG

Please don't yell at me if i made smth stupid. Im trying to make a website for my classes.

```
<p> help </p>
```

Comment: the image src is not there.

Comment: Psst. You're not using Java.

Comment: Read [mcve] and improve your question. Please. Dramatically.

Comment: you have to give relative image path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".img-w").each(function() {
    $(this).wrap("<div class='img-c'></div>")
    let imgSrc = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
     $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imgSrc + ')');
  })
            
  
  $(".img-c").click(function() {
    let w = $(this).outerWidth()
    let h = $(this).outerHeight()
    let x = $(this).offset().left
    let y = $(this).offset().top
    
    
    $(".active").not($(this)).remove()
    let copy = $(this).clone();
    copy.insertAfter($(this)).height(h).width(w).delay(500).addClass("active")
    $(".active").css('top', y - 8);
    $(".active").css('left', x - 8);
    
      setTimeout(function() {
    copy.addClass("positioned")
  }, 0)
    
  }) 
  
  

  
})

$(document).on("click", ".img-c.active", function() {
  let copy = $(this)
  copy.removeClass("positioned active").addClass("postactive")
  setTimeout(function() {
    copy.remove();
  }, 500)
})
```

```css
html,
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.all {
 width: 100%;
}
.center {
  transform: translate(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 50%;
}

.paint {
 padding-top: 55%;
 font-family: 'Quicksand';
 font-size: 30px;
}

.menu {
 background-color: transparent;
 width: 100%;
}

.menu a {
 float: right;
 display: block;
 color: black;
 font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 17px;
 padding-right: 50px;
 padding-left: 50px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-top: 10px;
}

.menu a:hover {
 background-color: #ddd;
 color: black;
}

.menu .icon {
 display: none;
}
@-ms-viewport{
  width: device-width;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .menu a:not(:last-child) {
  display: none;
 }
 .menu a.icon {
  float: right;
  display: block;
 
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .menu.responsive {
  position: relative;
 }
 .menu.responsive a.icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
 }
 .menu.responsive a {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: middle;
 }
}
body {
  padding: 30px 0;
  position: relative;
}

.gallery {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  //position: relative;
}
.img-c {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-w {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform ease-in-out 300ms;
}

.img-w img {
  display: none;
}

.img-c {
    transition: width ease 400ms, height ease 350ms, left cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 420ms, top cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 420ms;
}

.img-c:hover .img-w {
  transform: scale(1.08);
  transition: transform cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 450ms;
}

.img-c.active {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  //transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.img-c.postactive {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.img-c.active.positioned {
  left: 0 !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  transition-delay: 50ms;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,500" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Kinga Błaszczyk</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="all">
  <div class="menu" id="myMenu">
   <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
   <a href="#about">About</a>
   <a href="#myart">My Art</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  </div>
   
  <div class="center">
   <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/15/3c/38/153c381fbb537893047153bad1819568.jpg">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="paint" style="text-align: center;">
   <p>MY ART </p>
  </div>
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="img-w">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485766410122-1b403edb53db?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=846&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485793997698-baba81bf21ab?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485871800663-71856dc09ec4?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=2250&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485871882310-4ecdab8a6f94?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=2250&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485872304698-0537e003288d?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485872325464-50f17b82075a?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470171119584-533105644520?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=886&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485881787686-9314a2bc8f9b?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=969&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485889397316-8393dd065127?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=843&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="" /></div>
</div>  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help :>

Comment: @Kinga Are you happy with my answer?

Comment: Yes because i can finally see images, not mine but thats something ;D

Comment: @Kinga Because, if so, remember to click the check mark next to my answer to 'accept' it, so everyone knows the problem is solved.

Comment: Got it :> appreciate ur help

Comment: @Kinga Always a pleasure. Enjoy coding your site!

Answer (score 0):

Because it cant find the image you're assigning.

```
   <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech"/>
```

placeimg is a generated image.

I made some edits to your codepen and forked it.

You also didnt include `jquery`.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awooQB

Comment: jquery? u made images appear i get it (cuz of placeming) but why my images dont want to show, even if i have them in same location file as html?

Comment: I think your images are not in te same directory as your html file.

Answer (score 0):

In your codepen example you have the following

```
 <div class="gallery">
  <div class="img-w"><img src="1.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="2.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="3.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="4.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="5.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="6.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="7.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="sunset.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="10.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
</div>
```

For the images to show in your webpage, the files must be saved in the same location as the html file.  So, make sure the images `1.jpg`, `2.jpg` etc are in the same folder as your html file and they should display as you want them to.

Additionally, using `relative paths` (i.e. that refer to a file relative to the html by only providing a partial path) like this will mean that your images will never show up on codepen as it has no access to the images.

To make images show up on codepen you need to publish them to the internet somehow (beyond the scope of this question) and use the full URL to the published image (it should start with http:// or https://)

On looking at the CSS though you also have

```
.img-w img {
  display: none;
}
```

Removing the `display:none` means the images are displayed, however, i think you want to get the JQuery to work so you should add references to JQuery to your HTML file and then the images will be displayed as per the example below:

**Snippet:**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".img-w").each(function() {
    $(this).wrap("<div class='img-c'></div>")
    let imgSrc = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
     $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + imgSrc + ')');
  })
            
  
  $(".img-c").click(function() {
    let w = $(this).outerWidth()
    let h = $(this).outerHeight()
    let x = $(this).offset().left
    let y = $(this).offset().top
    
    
    $(".active").not($(this)).remove()
    let copy = $(this).clone();
    copy.insertAfter($(this)).height(h).width(w).delay(500).addClass("active")
    $(".active").css('top', y - 8);
    $(".active").css('left', x - 8);
    
      setTimeout(function() {
    copy.addClass("positioned")
  }, 0)
    
  }) 
  
  

  
})

$(document).on("click", ".img-c.active", function() {
  let copy = $(this)
  copy.removeClass("positioned active").addClass("postactive")
  setTimeout(function() {
    copy.remove();
  }, 500)
})
```

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.all {
    width: 100%;
}
.center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.paint {
    padding-top: 55%;
    font-family: 'Quicksand';
    font-size: 30px;
}

.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  //position: relative;
}
.img-c {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-w {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform ease-in-out 300ms;
}

.img-w img {
  display: none;
}

.img-c {
    transition: width ease 400ms, height ease 350ms, left cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 420ms, top cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 420ms;
}

.img-c:hover .img-w {
  transform: scale(1.08);
  transition: transform cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 450ms;
}

.img-c.active {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  //transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.img-c.postactive {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.img-c.active.positioned {
  left: 0 !important;
  top: 0 !important;
  transition-delay: 50ms;
}

.menu {
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 100%;
}

.menu a {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.menu a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.menu .icon {
    display: none;
}
@-ms-viewport{
  width: device-width;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .menu a:not(:last-child) {
        display: none;
    }
    .menu a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
    
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .menu.responsive {
        position: relative;
    }
    .menu.responsive a.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .menu.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: middle;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,500" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Kinga Błaszczyk</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="all">
  <div class="menu" id="myMenu">
   <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
   <a href="#about">About</a>
   <a href="#myart">My Art</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  </div>
   
  <div class="center">
   <img src="painter.png">
  </div>
  
  <div class="paint">
  <center>
   <p>MY ART </p>
   </center>
  </div>
 <div class="gallery">
  <div class="img-w"><img src="http://website-design-studio.net/finallinkB/wp-content/themes/suffusion/images/1.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="http://website-design-studio.net/finallinkB/wp-content/themes/suffusion/images/1.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="http://website-design-studio.net/finallinkB/wp-content/themes/suffusion/images/1.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="4.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="5.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="6.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="7.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="sunset.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
  <div class="img-w"><img src="10.jpg" alt="image" /></div>
</div>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

The answer to this question [linking jquery in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106864/linking-jquery-in-html) shows you how to add `JQuery` to your `HTML`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**Please note these are old files and should be replaced with the current versions of `JQuery`.**

Comment: They are saved in the same location as the html file.

Comment: checked. im sure

Comment: they wont show on codepen i know, but you can see earlier that theres small squar telling u, image should be there but we cant find it. i get that.

Comment: you should add references to JQuery to your HTML file and then the images will be displayed as per the example below - how to add those references?

Comment: Added instructions to add JQuery reference

Comment: Thank You very much. gonna add them and see

Comment: deleting .img-w img {
  display: none;
}

Comment: made me see images. but right everything got destroyed

Comment: @Kinga My answer should work for you now; I edited it